# How to read sub-levels of XML file with Vb.Net?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmldocument

Good day to everyone, I have this situation, I have the next XML file below, that has 2 sub-levels and I can't find the way to read it. this is the structure

```
<S:Envelope>
   <S:Body>
      <consultEdocument>
         <response>
            <result>
               <cove>
                  <transmitter>
                     <idetype>0</idetype>
                     <identification>58-249660700</identification>
                     <name>PRECISION INTERCONNECT INC.</name>
                     <address>
                        <street>SW FREEMAN COURT</street>
                        <ext_no>10025</ext_no>
                        <city>WILSONVILLE</city>
                        <country>USA</country>
                        <zipcode>97070-9289</zipcode>
                     </address>
                  </transmitter>
                  <addressee>
                     <idetype>1</idetype>
                     <identification>MTK861014317</identification>
                     <name>MAQUILAS TETA KAWI SA DE CV</name>
                     <address>
                        <street>GUADALAJARA-NOGALES</street>
                        <ext_no>KM 1969</ext_no>
                        <city>EMPALME</city>
                        <country>MEX</country>
                        <zipcode>85340</zipcode>
                     </address>
                  </addressee>
               </cove>
            </result>
         </response>
      </consultEdocument>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I need to get firstly the transmitter's street to save it in a variable, then I need to get addressee's street but notice that in both cases has the tag name "street" so when I try to catch that value it shows me NullReferenceException. So I don't know if it is because the tag name, this is my code.

```
Public Sub process_xml(ByVal xmlfile As String)

        Dim xml_doc As XmlDocument
        xml_doc = New XmlDocument
        xml_doc.Load("C:\" + xmlfile)


        Dim name_space_mgr = New XmlNamespaceManager(xml_doc.NameTable)
        name_space_mgr.AddNamespace("S", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
        name_space_mgr.AddNamespace("wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")
        name_space_mgr.AddNamespace("wsu", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility")


        Dim identification_type_transmitter = ""
        Dim tax_id_transmitter = ""
        Dim name_transmitter = ""
        Dim paternal_surname_transmitter = ""
        Dim maternal_surname_transmitter = ""
        Dim street_transmitter = ""
        Dim ext_num_transmitter = ""
        Dim int_num_transmitter = ""
        Dim zipcode_transmitter = ""
        Dim neighborhood_transmitter = ""
        Dim city_transmitter = ""
        Dim federal_entity_transmitter = ""
        Dim county_transmitter = ""
        Dim country_transmitter = ""

        Dim nodelist = xml_doc.GetElementsByTagName("transmitter")

        For Each node As XmlElement In nodelist
            identification_type_transmitter = node("idetype").InnerText.ToString()
            tax_id_transmitter = node("identification").InnerText.ToString()
            name_transmitter = node("name").InnerText.ToString()
        Next

        'NOTE THAT I TRIED WITH DIFFERENT WAYS AND THEY DIDN T WORK 
        Dim nodelist_transmitter = xml_doc.SelectNodes("//S:Envelope/S:Body/consultEdocument/response/result/cove/transmitter/address/street/").ItemOf(0)
        Dim nodelist_transmitter = xml_doc.SelectNodes("address").ItemOf(0)'

        Dim nodelist_transmitter = xml_doc.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='address']").ItemOf(0)
        For Each node As XmlElement In nodelist_transmitter

            street_transmitter = node("street").InnerText.ToString() 'Here is the NullReferenceException'
            ext_num_transmitter = node("ext_no").InnerText.ToString()

            '.... another tags'
        Next

        'Make some processes with data....'
    End Sub
```

So I tried with some ways but without success.. How can I do this?
Thanks you!

Comment: I don't see the tag name "emisor" in the xml you posted.

Comment: Sorry I already fix it

Answer (score 0):

The following code works to select the two elements:

```
Dim xml_doc As New XmlDocument()
xml_doc.Load("C:\" + xmlfile)
Dim name_space_mgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(xml_doc.NameTable)
name_space_mgr.AddNamespace("S", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
Dim transmitterAddressNode As XmlNode = xml_doc.SelectSingleNode("//S:Envelope/S:Body/consultEdocument/response/result/cove/transmitter/address/street", name_space_mgr)
Dim addresseeAddressNode As XmlNode = xml_doc.SelectSingleNode("//S:Envelope/S:Body/consultEdocument/response/result/cove/addressee/address/street", name_space_mgr)
```

The key difference, is that, in my example, I am passing the name space manager as an argument into the select method.

(Also, in order to get it to work, I had to insert the namespace declaration into your sample XML document: `<S:Envelope xmlns:S='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>`.  Without that, the XML document is not well-formed.)

Comment: In my case these Xml files are provided from another company and I get them as the example. Also I tried the code that you provide me and in my case `transmitterAddressNode` is Nothing and I don't get any value.

Comment: I notice that the original Xml file has that line that you specified `<S:Envelope xmlns:S='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>` and anyway it did not work

Comment: Please post an actual example of an XML document which fails with my example.

Comment: Here is the actual xml document [link](https://www.mediafire.com/?5pwmvhan5jl4qd7).

Comment: I tried my exact code with that exact document (from your link) and it worked.  So, if it's not working for you, there must be something else wrong.

Comment: I search in my function what could be wrong and I can't find any error but maybe there is something making that conflict on my code, I'm going to check again and I will post what I find